# Take a string in one column, and append it to a list in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns, one is a string, another is a list of strings.

How do I append the string to the list of strings?

What I tried:

```
df['Combined'] = df['string'] + df['ListOfStrings']
```

and

```
df['Combined'] = df['string'].to_list() + df['ListOfStrings']
```

Possible method:

Turn the string column into a list containing a single element, then try the method in my first attempt. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: kindly share sample data, with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a list comprehension:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'string':['a','b','c'],
    'ListOfStrings':[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5']]
})

df['Combined'] = [a+[b] for a,b in zip(df['ListOfStrings'],df['string'])]
```

Output:

```
  string ListOfStrings   Combined
0      a        [1, 2]  [1, 2, a]
1      b        [3, 4]  [3, 4, b]
2      c           [5]     [5, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the **df['string']** into list brackets, like this:

```
df['Combined'] = [df['string']] + df['ListOfStrings']
```

That way you won't have any issues performing this operation.